# Select Option hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="dropdownPName" name="company">
  <option value="A">Comapny A</option>
  <option value="B">Company B</option>
  <option value="Walk-in">Walk-in</option>
  <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

I want if, the selected is "Others" a text box will appear so the user will specify the company

Comment: So what have you tried so far.?

Comment: if(**I want**) die();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textbox html

```
<input type="text" id="cmpny_txbx" name="cmpny_txbx" />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cmpny_txbx").hide();
  $("#dropdownPName").change(function(){
   if($("#dropdownPName").val() == 'Others'){
      //Show text box here
      $("#cmpny_txbx").show();
   }
   else{
     //Hide text box here
     $("#cmpny_txbx").hide();
   }
    });
});
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uquSAku/1/edit)**

Comment: You can even make it shorter, using `toggle()`.

Comment: why in my form it's not working?
the input type text is not showing up...

Answer (score 0):

Create one text box, place it where you want and style it accordingly

```
<input type="text" id="comp" name="othercompany" placeholder="Enter company name" style="display:none;" />
```

To get value of select box you use

```
pName = document.getElementById('dropdownPName');
var value = pName.options[pName.selectedIndex].value;
if(value.toLowerCase() == 'others')
{
    var ele = document.getElementById('comp');
     ele.style.display = "block";
}
```